# Using Babel: How to protect translator comments (and old translations) in GNU gettext PO files?

Tags: python, gettext, python-babel

With the Python-based [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/) gettext utilities, are there any techniques to preserve translator comments and old ("obsolete") translations (marked with `#~`) in `.po` files across updates from the `.pot` file?

The first time an obsolete translation is in a `.po` file, and `pybabel update` is run, the translation is marked with `#~`. This is so that on the one hand, it is treated as a comment and not used until a translator looks it over and changes it, yet on the other hand, it is not removed, so a translator can refer to it, or copy text from it into their other translations.

However, the next time `pybabel update` is run, all comments are permanently removed from the file. This means those translations marked with `#~` are removed, too.

For example, with Babel version 0.9.6 and [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) version 2.6, and the following files:

**`./babel.ini`**:

```
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
encoding = utf-8
```

**`./templates/test.html`**:

```
<html><body>
<h1>{% trans %}My website{% endtrans %}</h1>
</body></html>
```

**`./i18n/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po`**:

```
# ... header stuff generated from
#     pybabel init -l pt_PT -d i18n -i i18n/messages.pot ...

# Don't forget, I want to remember something about this!
#~ msgid "My web page"
#~ msgstr "A minha página de web"
```

After the following commands are run:

```
$ pybabel extract -F babel.ini -o i18n/messages.pot .
$ pybabel update -l pt_PT -d i18n -i i18n/messages.pot
```

The Portuguese `messages.po` file loses all its old comments, and contains only:

**`./i18n/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po`**:

```
# ... similar header stuff ...

#: templates/test.html:2
msgid "My web site"
msgstr ""
```

How can I update my translation files without losing my comments and old translations?

Comment: Can you specify which libraries you are using, and supply an example file?

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using pybabel update use **msgmerge** from [gettext utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgmerge-Invocation.html#msgmerge-Invocation)

In your case it would be:

**`msgmerge ./i18n/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po ./i18n/messages.pot -o ./i18n/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po`**

Example:

having **`reference.pot`** file:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: templates/test.html:2
msgid "My web site"
msgstr ""
```

and **`pt_previous.po`** file with your previous translations:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language-Team: \n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Language: pt\n"

# Don't forget, I want to remember something about this!
#~ msgid "My web site"
#~ msgstr "A minha página de web"
```

Running a command:

**`msgmerge pt_previous.po reference.pot -o pt_new.po`**

Will make **`./pt_new.po`** file which looks like this:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: pt\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

# Don't forget, I want to remember something about this!
#: templates/test.html:2
msgid "My web site"
msgstr "A minha página de web"
```